# VS2015 - How do I attach the profiler to a cloud project?

Tags: visual-studio, profiling, visual-studio-2015

In the previous version of Visual Studio I would follow this guide https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/cloud-services-performance-testing-visual-studio-profiler/

However in the latest VS I do not see the Attach/Detach option under Profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has actually moved to ***Debug => Profiler => Performance Explorer => Attach/Detach***

It's only visible when you are not attached to anything.